# How to pause video based on video.currentTime using whole numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

```
<video id="js-video" autoplay>
   <source src="./vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video> 
<button id="js-button">
</button>

var video = document.getElementById('js-video');
var button = document.getElementById('js-button');
var data = [
     { pauseTime: 2,
       image: "./foo_1.png"
     },{
      pauseTime: 6,
      image: "./foo_2.png"
     }
    ];

    function showOverlay() {
     video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
      var full = parseInt(video.currentTime);

        console.log(video.currentTime);

      for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (full === data[i].pauseTime) {
          video.pause();
          moveToNextScene();
        } else {
          console.log("else");
        }
      }
     });
    }

   function moveToNextScene() {
      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        video.play();
      });
    }

    showOverlay();
```

I have a video and using the data array, I would like to pause the video at the `pauseTime` in the objects inside the data array and place an overlay image on top of it.

The problem I'm having is that the `timeUpdate` event returns a decimal number so I have to call `parseInt` on it but in that case the video keeps pausing at all the intervals between 2 whole numbers, eg: if I want to pause at 2 seconds, it will pause several times between 2.000001 all the way to 2.999999, but I just want it to pause once around 2.000001 (doesn't have to be exact) and no more until the next `pauseTime`, in this case 6.
I wrote `video[0].currentTime += 1;` in the `if` statement and it fixes this problem but then it jumps by one sec and I don't want that.

You can see what I mean here: https://jsfiddle.net/njbn0ddn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a more formal way of noting completion of the event. Here we note wether we have hit that stopping point, and if we have, we move on without checking the time again. Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/meqnz2vj/

```
var video = document.getElementById('js-video');
    var button = document.getElementById('js-button');
    var data = [
         { pauseTime: 2,
           image: "./foo_1.png",
           got_here:false
         },{
          pauseTime: 6,
          image: "./foo_2.png",
          got_here:false
         }
        ];

        function showOverlay() {
         video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
          var full = parseInt(video.currentTime);

            console.log(video.currentTime);

          for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (full === data[i].pauseTime && data[i].got_here == false) {
              data[i].got_here = true;
              video.pause();
              moveToNextScene();
            } else {
              console.log("else");
            }
          }
         });
        }

       //when paused, a button will appear, on closing it, the vide resumes
       function moveToNextScene() {
          button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            video.play();
          });
        }

        showOverlay();
```